# Cannot load pretrained model for continue training

Tags: pytorch, load

I trained my own model but decided to continue training.
When I use the code below, my model shows high BCELoss as it is a non-trained model.
Where is the problem?
Thank you

```
model_1 = SimpleCnn(n_classes) # model class
model_1.load_state_dict(torch.load('./model.pth', map_location='cuda:0'))
model_1.to(DEVICE) # torch cuda device
history = train(train_dataset, val_dataset, model=model_1, epochs=8, batch_size=16) # train function
torch.save(model_1.state_dict(), 'model_1.pth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to continue training, you need to save not only the `state_dict` of the model, but of the optimizer's as well.

That is, during training, you need to save not only the trained weights of the model, but some other parameters. For example:

```py
def train_function(...):
  for e in range(num_epochs):
    ...
  # when done training
  torch.save({'model', model.state_dict(),
              'opt', optimizer.state_dict(),
              'lr', lr_sched.state_dict(),  # you also need to save the state of the learning rate scheduler
              ...  # there might be other things that define the "state" of your training
             }, PATH)
```

Then, if you resume training:

```py
checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['opt'])
lr_sched.load_state_dict(checkpoint['lr'])
... # might need to restore other things
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean and what shall I do? 
In train function I'm using 
`opt = torch.optim.Adamax(model.parameters(), lr=0.0002)`
Then I do backward, step and so on.
What should I save?

Comment: You mean to do:
torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), PATH)
?

Comment: I think It will be the solution
I will try and then tell you and upvote in case it works